# Get Uploaded image back in Edit View Textboxfor input type file MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get back image file into textboxfor `type="file"` image is back but `RequiredAttribute` not allow to add because image shown as empty how can I get

Here is I am using `TextBoxFor` type is file. On save working perfect but cannot retrieve image back

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image, new {value=Model.Image, type = "File" })      
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Here is my controller all the field is getting well except image

In my mode I simply use Image type string that work perfect.

Image save in folder and path in database well

```
public ActionResult Edit(int StudentId)
{
    StudentViewModel collection = new StudentViewModel();
    StudentServices ser = new StudentServices();
    Student students = db.Students.Find(StudentId);
    ViewBag.Image = students.Image;
    ViewBag.Date = students.DOB.Value.ToShortDateString();
    ViewBag.CountryDDL = new SelectList(GetCountry(), "CountryId", "Name", students.CountryId);
    return View(students);
}
```

At last sorry for Poor English.

Comment: You cannot for security reasons - the value of a file input can only be set by the user selecting a file in the browser. And as a side note, remove the pointless `new { value=Model.Image }`. And why in the world are you setting  those `ViewBag` for `Image` and `Date` when they are already in your model.

Comment: And `TextBoxFor(m => m.Image)` makes no sense since `Image` is cleary not typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` which it needs to be in order to bind to your model property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i Just use ViewBag to make try to get image nothing else and any solution for no file chosen text get fill with selected image name

Comment: Again, you cannot. Just display the file name as text in the view so that the user knows what they previously selected, and include the file input so they can select a different one if they want. (you may want to look at [this project](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-filehelper) for some ideas)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks alot... you are best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set image to `type="file"` input.
The other solution you may follow is:

- Retrieve image path (considering you save it in some folder and not
  as binary in DB) and show the image in `<img />` tag (or an anchor
  link `<a />` with the path of the image), this is for user to see the
  old image.
- When click the edit button, you check if the user uploaded new image or not, if the user did then save the new uploaded image and remove the old one, if didn't then just don't change any thing in old image.

Comment: "No File Chosen" that text also replace with image name actually i get image back but a this "No File Chosen" text not filled with image name and Required validation occur

Comment: How did you get the image back ?

Comment: I getting back from Jquery    var RetriveImage = function (file) {
            var value = $("#ImageID").val();
            $("#targetImg").attr('src', value);
            $("#imgPreview").show();
        }